# JTextArea---last charcter not selected

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I am using `JTextArea` in a frame to show some text file, with following properties

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

The data in the file contains long lines(html headers and body stuff).
Now when I try to select the text using mouse, am not able to select the last character of
a wrapped line unless I select the next line too.

Also you can try running this example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
     class frame extends JFrame{ 
        JTextArea t=new JTextArea(); 
        public frame(){ 
           t.setLineWrap(true);
           this.add(t);
           t.setText("jhdbjcdbhhdjbcjbjbjbsjbcsbjsbcjsbcksnkniuhihdehsdbjsbcjbcbccccccccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc ccccccccccccccc");}
       public static void main(String[] args){
       frame f=new frame();
       f.setSize(500,500);
       f.setVisible(true); }
   }
```

Comment: `this.add(t);` should probably be `this.add(new JScrollPane(t));`..

Comment: BTW - in real usage, is the text area *ever* likely to contain such long strings of text with no space characters?

Comment: well, yes sometimes.
am using it to display http rquests and response data.
and i am using ScrollPane but i need to wrap lines horizontally
which is all working fine but when a line without a space if wrapped, i am not able to select(using mouse) the last character 
of that line without taking the cursor to next line.
even       
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true)
doesn't help as there are no space characters between words.